# android edittext does not show custom cursor when orientation change

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a standard EditText which looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/mycursor"
    android:minLines="3"/>
```

Which is fine. It shows on the screen and works great but as soon as I change orientation from portrait to landscape, the editText changes to slightly different UI, with a "Done" button to the right and all. This is still fine but the problem is it goes back to showing the default cursor and not mycursor.

Any idea how can I fix this so that mycursor will show no matter what the orientation is?

Comment: Are you using implementing a portrait and landscape layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe version with the done button is the extract view.  Its actually not drawn by your app, its drawn by the keyboard itself.  Since its being drawn by another app, anything special in the UI will not be honored, such as cursors, because the keyboard app doesn't know about them.  You can set the imeOption flagNoExtractUi to try to prevent this from happening, but that may cause a bad experience on small phones, as only a tiny sliver of app will fit on screen above the keyboard.